# How can I preserver SSL on subdomain with htaccess rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(piwik|www)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to force "www" on the root of domain.com. Using the method above I can access piwik.domain.com insecurely (http://) but not over SSL. When I try accessing https://piwik.domain.com I am redirected to https://www.domain.com.

The SSL certificate is installed to *.domain.com

Edit: Subdomains Configuration

- *.domain.com -> public_html
- piwik.domain.com -> public_html/subdomain/piwik

Edit: Entire contents of htaccess

```
suphp_configpath /home/moninsha/public_html

###Redirect non-www urls to it's exact match www URL 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(piwik|www)\.moninstore\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.moninstore.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "modification plus 2 weeks" 
</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Show your rule that redirects `http -> https`

Comment: @anubhava, I have added my htaccess file and subdomain setup. The only other thing that controls redirection is the PHP in the magento store on domain.conm. The unsecure url is set to http://www.domain.com and the secure URL set to https://www.domain.com

Comment: ok I didn't know magento is also there. magento needs some URL config like https or http in `magento preferences` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by default the HTTPS protocol will default to one domain. If you have any subdomains you wish to map with a wildcard SSL certificate you will need to do so using .htaccess rewrites like the following:

Since, for me, domain.com is mapped to ~/public_html/ and assuming that piwik.domain.com is mapped to ~/public_html/subdomain/piwik/ you would use the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/piwik/ 
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piwik.domain.com 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/piwik/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

Then just clear your local browser's cache.